# regex to match everything but substrings beginning with hashkey

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

I am building a regex to filter out any substrings beginning with '#' or '@'. I am trying to filter tweets from those. Currently it matches everything no matter if the string contains words beginning with a '#' or '@'.

```
((?!\#)|(?!\@)).*
```

In this string below I want to match everything in bold, but no more:

**Hi shah rukh. Who is your co-actor in the upcoming movie?** @iamsrk #lovefrommalaysia #askSRK

I want to keep the whitespaces between the words in bold. How can I achieve this? This will be used in python FYI.

Comment: Inverse problem here: http://superuser.com/q/820361/76571

Comment: @Excellll That's what I did, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind matching everything except substrings beginning with '@' or '#'. I just did the opposite and used re.sub in python to remove those from the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Hi shah rukh. Who is your co-actor in the upcoming movie? @iamsrk #lovefrommalaysia #askSRK'
>>> text = re.sub(r'([\#\@].*?)(?=([\r\n ]|$))', '', text).strip()
>>> print text
Hi shah rukh. Who is your co-actor in the upcoming movie?
```

Brief explanation:

1. Matching group #1 `([\#\@].*?)` groups either # or @ together with as few characters following (non-greedy).
2. Positive lookahead `(?=([\r\n ]|$))` tries to match either a carriage return, new line, space or end of string without including it in the result.

I don't know how elegant this solution is, but it works for my use. Try it on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3bhli)